Is there a way to give a ring structure on symmetric group $S_n$?
I know that $S_n$ is non-commutative group with operation $\circ$. And I know it is impossible to force $S_n$ to be a ring with that operation $\circ$.
My question is that Can we give a ring structure on symmetric group $S_n$ with usual operations of functions $+,\cdot$?
I mean $(S_n,+)$ is abelian group and $(S_n,\cdot)$ is semigroup and we have distribution law over the addition.
Of course, I know that if we have abelian group $A$ then we can define multiplication $*$ such that $a*b=0$, $\forall a,b \in A$. But that operation is trivial one. So according to this construciton every abelian group has trivial ring structure.

What operations on $S_n$ are you referring to with $+$ and $\cdot$? How do you add/multiply two permutations to yield another one?

The pointwise sum of two bijections ${0, 1, ..., n-1} \to {0, 1, ..., n-1}$ mod $n$ is not usually a bijection. So, one should instead consider all functions from ${0, 1, ..., n-1}$ to itself, not just the bijections. In that case, one would then have a near-ring, where only one of the distributive laws ($(f+g) \circ h=(f \circ h)+(g \circ h)$) holds, but not the other one ($f \circ (g+h)=(f \circ g)+(f \circ h)$).

You can always define the group ring for nice enough groups (finite groups are such an example). I don't know if that's what you're looking for though.

What you can do is form the group ring $\mathbb{Z}[S_3]$, which would contain a copy of $S_3$ as part of its multiplicative structure.

I wanted to give ring structure on $S_n$. That leads me to think that which operations that I have for functions such as $+$, $\cdot$. I thought maybe they might work and operations are $(f+g) (x)=f(x)+g(x)$ and similarly for multiplication.

For "$(f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x)$" to make sense, you also need a structure of addition and multiplication on the set ${1,2,3}$ that you are acting on; otherwise, the expression does not make sense (the right hand side is undefined). What structure do you have on ${1,2,3}$ to make this even start to make sense?

You may be interested in a group ring which allows you to put a ring structure onto any group in a natural way. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring

Thank you very much for guideness. @ArturoMagidin, you are absolutely right. I chose $f=Id$ and $g=(12)$ then $(f+g)(3)=6 \not \in {1,2,3}$. Hence,  I thought it might be useful to look at it in mod $3$, but it didn't work. Again $(f+g)(3)\equiv 0 \not \in {1,2,3}$. Mod seems to me that not useful. What should I do?

If you don't care about the fact that the elements are permutations then you are just looking for a ring with $n!$ elements, with no predefined "usual operations" for addition and multiplication. For that you can use the integers modulo $n!$.
If permutation composition must be one of the operations then the answer is "no". It can't be the ring addition, because it's noncommutative. It can't be the ring multiplication since whatever the $0$ is for addition must give $0$ when multiplied by anything.

What if we care the elements? I mean I want to use permutations.

@Elise9 Use them in what way? My answer shows that the obvious ways to convert permutation properties to ring properties don't work.   I can't think of any others. I doubt that they exist. Commentts pointing you to the group ring are probably the best you'll get.
